# How to reference multiple authors of a chapter from a book [APA]?

Tags: citation-style

I need help deciding how to cite a specific chapter of a group for my thesis. 
My problem is basically with the different types of authors the chapters of this book has. 
The authors titles are: Coordinating Lead author, Lead Authors, Contributing Authors and Review editors.
So, which ones do I include?

Comment: Could you give an example? Also what citation style are you using (APA, MLA)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am currently using the APA citation style.

Comment: The following is the chapter i need to cite. 
Chapter 17
Cultural and Amenity Services
Coordinating Lead Authors: Rudolf de Groot, P.S. Ramakrishnan
Lead Authors: Agnes van de Berg, Thaya Kulenthran, Scott Muller, David Pitt, Dirk Wascher, Gamini
Wijesuriya
Contributing Authors: Bas Amelung, Nesa Eliezer, Aspara Ram Gopal, Mechtild Ro¨ ssler
Review Editors: Xu Jianchu, Hebe Vessuri

Comment: I really wish i could post it with the proper paragraphs. My problem is that there are 4 different author titles. i dont know which to choose or if there is a priority. 
every chapter has different authors as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [APA blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/02/books-and-book-chapters-what-to-cite.html) this is what you need to site in APA

> Author, A. A. (Year). Title of chapter. In B. B. Editor (Ed.), Title
>   of book [E-reader version, if applicable] (pp. xxx–xxx). Retrieved
>   from http://xxxxx

You will see in the [purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/06/) that you should only list seven authors. So your chapter citation should look like this. I'm assuming this is the chapter you are referring to at this [link](http://www.millenniumassessment.org/documents/document.286.aspx.pdf).

> De Groot, R, Ramakrishnan, P.S, Van De Berg, A,  Kulenthran,, T, Muller, S, Pitt, D, ... Rossler, M. (2005). 
>   Chapter 17 Cultural and Amenity Services (Xu Jianchu and Hebe
>   Vessuri Ed.). In  Rashid Hassan, Robert Scholes, and Neville Ash (Ed.), *Ecosystems and Human Well-being: Current State and Trends* (Vol. 1, The Millennium Ecosystem Assessment, pp. 455-476). Washington: Island Press.

For in text citations use the following [link](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/03/)

> Six or More Authors: Use the first author's name followed by et al. in the signal phrase or in parentheses.
>
> Harris et al. (2001) argued...
>
> (Harris et al., 2001)

Comment: thank you very much for your help in this. I had no idea about the seven authors part.

Comment: @YiannisPaneras no problem. If the answer helped you, you can upvote it and accept. That's the usual way for thanking on this site.